# Getting an Image to auto-resize inside a CSS Grid

Tags: html, css

Very beginner to HTML/CSS and I need some help with fitting in image inside a CSS Grid.

I have created a simple CSS grid and when I'm trying to fit an image inside one of the grid, I was able to get width to fit properly, but the height is something that will not change.

I've tried obejct-fit, max-height with ratios...etc.

Would you please help and guide me on how to get this done?

This is my codepen currently working on: https://codepen.io/jyjang703/pen/poodOgw

```css
#main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 250px 300px 300px auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header" "section1 section2 section3 section4" "footer footer footer footer";
}

#title {
  grid-area: header;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#section1 {
  grid-area: section1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

#section1 img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#section2 {
  grid-area: section2;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#section3 {
  grid-area: section3;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#section4 {
  grid-area: section4;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">

  <header id="title">
    <h1> Allen Iverson</h1>
  </header>

  <section id="section1">
    <div id="img-div">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://fsa.zobj.net/crop.php?r=FwHUQXbzIfSpz4awUIaTcY3NIgHVe1mSFMPlsB6rpnNmbj9mHPRpVHtH7c8RgxuGUffOqlWYgSbRNw4hXsKEL4NpVjgwRglygtByR-SVELuRZrvPVOfhBVpCkcS0FNh74XcecRFJpdkNtQwOy_rZO2Ftc5H606i6-pDgEjbe2Aqrn3yUNiwkTPLkq34" alt="">
        <figcaption>
          It's not about size, it's about size of your heart
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section2">
  </section>

  <section id="section3">
  </section>

  <section id="section4">
  </section>

  <footer id="footer">
    I am a Footer
  </footer>
</main>
```

Comment: It's because the HTML figure tag removes whatever is inside of it from the flow of the document, so its position won't work as you're hoping.  Let me see if I can fix it with limited changes to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `#img-div`. Convert the `figure` to a flexbox, and constrain it's height:

```
#section1 figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Set the `img`s flex to 1, and use `min-height: 0` to let it shrink:

```
#section1 img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

Example (click **run** and then **full page**):

```css
#main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 250px 300px 300px auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header" "section1 section2 section3 section4" "footer footer footer footer";
}

#title {
  grid-area: header;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#section1 {
  grid-area: section1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#section1 figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

#section1 img {
  object-fit: scale-down;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
}

#section2 {
  grid-area: section2;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#section3 {
  grid-area: section3;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#section4 {
  grid-area: section4;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">

  <header id="title">
    <h1> Allen Iverson</h1>
  </header>

  <section id="section1">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://fsa.zobj.net/crop.php?r=FwHUQXbzIfSpz4awUIaTcY3NIgHVe1mSFMPlsB6rpnNmbj9mHPRpVHtH7c8RgxuGUffOqlWYgSbRNw4hXsKEL4NpVjgwRglygtByR-SVELuRZrvPVOfhBVpCkcS0FNh74XcecRFJpdkNtQwOy_rZO2Ftc5H606i6-pDgEjbe2Aqrn3yUNiwkTPLkq34" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        It's not about size, it's about size of your heart
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>

  <section id="section2">
  </section>

  <section id="section3">
  </section>

  <section id="section4">
  </section>

  <footer id="footer">
    I am a Footer
  </footer>
</main>
```